# Check user performing query

Tags: c#, sql-server

How do I find out which user is use to perform query (Entity Framework) when I run my program as Debug. I've got big problem with .mdf file which claim that database is read only when trying save something. I've got database in project (not my assumption) which is versioned (TFS). Ofc in visual studio 2012 i can add new row to this .mdf file.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to trace queries

Comment: Does your connection string include things like `user instance = true` and `attachDbFileName`? If so, STOP USING THOSE FEATURES. Attach your database to a proper instance of SQL Server and stop using file-based copies.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this file-based copies aren't my idea. Personally i'm very sad that there is database I have to download instead of script or database comparer feature. I have to update it... don't know how :|

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. You want to fix the problem? You need to fix the process.

Answer (score 0):

Open in Windows Explorer the folder containing the mdf file, right click on it, and remove read only. Or you cab right click on it in solution explorer and select "check out for edit". The problem should be that the file is read only (file are read only by default when you take them from source control)

However, you will have a lot of problems synchronizing that mdf file in source control. You should really take it out.

Comment: That's not the solution due to something make it read only again.

Comment: What makes it read only again ? If you use "check out for edit" it should stay without readonly until you check in the pending changes (unless you manually change that). The same happens with all the files, but VS has a setting which automatically checks out all the files you modify with it if they are on the source control. That is why you can use the database from VS, but not at runtime.

Comment: checkout for edit is not active for my .mdf file (File->Source Control->Check out for edit)

Comment: Ok, i made it 'Checked out for edit' but it still doesn't work. Same problem, database is read only

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server LocalDB would almost certainly solve this issue. LocalDB is pretty much designed to be used in the manner you are attempting.

For the most basic method, use a connection string like this:

```
Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
```

Comment: data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=True; that's not a problem i quess

Answer (score 0):

You have the project version of the mdf file version controlled in TFS, and TFS uses the readonly flag. When you debug, it's copying the file out to the run directory, and copying the readonly flag along with it. I would suggest putting in a post build script to remove the readonly flag. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx http://malektips.com/dos0031.html#.U3_HAdco4UQ